# How to retain value of manipulated bit using switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, bit-manipulation

I'm new to coding so my apologies if this is an obvious answer.  When running my program and I set bit 4, I get 16 which is correct.  When I choose to set another bit, for example 1; its returning 2 which is correct as well but I'm wanting to get the value of 18 by combining the previous entry from the user.  I'm sure I'm over-thinking it but I can't figure out where in my code the change should be made.  Thanks for the help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
      int value,bit,i,n,option;
      value = 0;

      printf("The current value is %d\n\n", value);

      while (1)
      {
         printf("\t(1) Set a bit\n");
         printf("\t(2) Clear a bit\n");
         printf("\t(3) Exit\n");
         printf("Enter your choice : ");
         scanf(" %d", &option);

         switch(option)
         {
           case 1:
            printf("Set which bit (0-31): ");
            scanf(" %d", &n);
            bit=0;
            bit = bit | (1 << n);
            printf("\nThe current value is %d\n\n", bit); 
            break;


           case 2:
            printf("Clear which bit (0-31): ");
            scanf(" %d", &n);
            bit=0;
            bit = bit & (~(1<<n));
            printf("\nThe current value is %d\n\n", bit);
            break;


           case 3:
            if(option==3)
            exit(0);

      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is code you wrote?  Why `bit=0;`?

Comment: I like that `case 3: if (option==3)`... double checking is always good!

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: MD XF forgive me for now formatting properly.  I was in a pinch at work and did the best I could given the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are resetting bit to 0 every time

```
  bit=0; /////<<<====
    bit = bit | (1 << n);
```

instead set bit to 0 at the start

```
int value,bit,i,n,option;
bit =0;
```

and remove the bit=0 line in the switch

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I made the change and its working properly now.

Comment: BTW more common idion is `bit |= (1 << n);` instead of `bit = bit | (1 << n);`